# How can I get DOM elements attributes name on a click, by JavaScript supposing the click can be anywhere on the page?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, attributes, element

Lets say I have html page, when ever user clicks on the page an event should occur on the press of a user click it should save all attributes behind that elements.

````
<head>
<script>
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement,
        text = target.textContent || target.innerText;   
}, false);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p style="color: green">
The content above was created with JavaScript.<br>
This content is created with <b>HTML</b>.<br>
You can edit JavaScript and HTML in the left part of the page
and click "<b>Run code</b>" to view results in the right part of the page.
</p>
<div id="dev1">
<p style="color: green">
The content above was created with JavaScript.<br>
Username : <input type="text" name="txtusername" id="username" > <br><br>
Password : <input type="Password" name="password" id="passname" >
</p>
</div>
<b>LESSON 4: CALL A JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION:</b>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: What's your problem - your var target should contain everything you need.

Comment: `e = e || window.event;` Wow...blast from the past. :-D

Comment: @T.J. IE is not dead, it's still haunting all over the world.

Comment: @Teemu - IE < 11 is dead. IE11 passes the event object to the handler. The code in the question would fail on any version of IE that didn't, as it uses `addEventListener`, not `attachEvent`.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear what you're asking here. As Mike said above, your `target` variable should refer to the clicked element. Your code currently accesses the text content of the clicked element, if it has any. (The `input` elements don't, they have `value`s.) If you need to get attributes from them, you'd either use the reflected property for the attribute (if it has one, like `href` or `src`) or `getAttribute("attr-name-here")`. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: I am tracking down all click events user is clicking anywhere on the page , on textbox, password box, checkbox by click I want to get attributes of that element so that I can store them and via ajax API call send it to google sheets. with which ML/DL algorithm will generate test cases with it

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes I am asking ` getAttribute("attr-name-here") `  when ever user click on the document event should listen get that attributes of that element.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to do so:

```
  document.onclick = function(event) {
    elem = event.target.attributes;
    console.log(event.target.attributes);
    attributes = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(elem);
    console.log(attributes)
  }
```

It will log the attributes of very element you click on the console, along with their values.

You need to access their keys.